Hyphenating attributive adjectives and the 'is' of identity vs. the 'is' of predication
I have a good grasp on the rule about hyphenating compound adjectives when they're in the attributive position – 'off-white car', 'climate-controlled shoes', etc. But there are some cases where this seems wrong to me and I am trying to articulate why.
Here's an example of what I have in mind:
(1) His land acquisition strategy was downright predatory.
(2) #  His land-acquisition strategy was downright predatory. #
Sentence (2) I am sure is wrong, but I am not sure I could explain correctly why. As far as I can tell, it is because you aren't attributing a quality to his strategy, but specifying his strategy, with 'land acquisition'. It isn't that his strategy is [predication] land acquisition, but that his strategy is [identity] (one of) land acquisition. So 'land acquisition' doesn't operate as an adjective here. Is this the correct explanation?

No, #2 is not wrong, but the hyphen should solve a confusion, and there would be none without it. So ...

If you look up "land acquisition strategy" you'll see that it is rarely if ever hyphenated, no matter where the phrase appears in a sentence. I doubt that anyone has 'a good grasp on the rule about hyphenating compound adjectives [/compound premodifiers in general] when they're in the attributive position' ... some examples are always hyphenated, others rarely if ever, and it's not just a matter of disambiguation. The 'rule' usually trotted out isn't inviolate,

And there are some style guides which are keener on hyphenation than others, as well as different people who have been taught slightly different rules. So it's hard to be too definite (there are edge cases to hyphenation rules e.g. when there's a preposition involved, when it conflicts with a common usage). But 2 sounds OK to me even though I wouldn't personally hyphenate because I'm a minimal-hyphen-user.

"His killing-all-the-Germans strategy won him the war" is certainly correct, and I think is the same as the OP.
